# Centralizar contendor div al clickear en menu de hotbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

Buenas noches como están? Les cuento, me gustaría poder al hacer clic en las diferentes opciones del menú, que cuando me redirija dentro de la pagina, el tamaño del contenedor ocupe toda la pantalla centrado y que no aparezcan partes de otros contenedores como me esta pasando ahora.
Ejemplo, la siguiente imagen tiene dos 3 contenedores que son  uno: donde están los diferentes skills (python java y postgreSQL) otro: la parte de contacto y el otro: el footer.
Y que el navbar no se me superponga.
Con CSS que atributos debería usar en los contenedores para mejorar esto?
Soy nuevo con esto y estoy agarrando practica por mi cuenta!
Desde ya muchas gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>STRS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script src="./js/scripts.js"></script>
    <link rel=”icon” href=”favicon.ico” type=”image/x-icon” />
    <link rel=”shortcut icon” href=”favicon.ico” type=”image/x-icon” />/*
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sacramento&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="hotbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home" id="navbar-home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#my-skills" id="navbar-my-skills">Skills</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact" id="navbar">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="btn-about"><a href="#about " id="navbar">About</a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div id="home" class="top-container">
        <h1>I'm Seba</h1>
        <h2>A junior developer</h2>
        <div class="img-profile">
            <img src="images/perfil.png" alt="perfil-png" width="200">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="about" class="middle-container">
        <div>
            <hr>
            <h2>Hellow welcome to my WebSite!!</h2>
            <p class="intro">Mi nombre es Sebastian. Soy estudiante de Ingenieria en sistemas.
            Actualmente trabajo com Tester de Software Ssr y ademas me gustaria trabajar ya sea de forma 
            freelance o fija como programador Fullstack. Cuento con conocimientos basicos de diferentes lenguajes
            los cuales detallo a continuacion.
            </p>
        </div>

        <hr>
        <div id="my-skills">
            <h2>My Skills</h2>
            <div class="skills" >
                        
                <div class="skill-row">
                    <div class="skill-name">
                        <img class="img-html5" src="images/html5.png" alt="html5-png" >
                        <h3>Html 5</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="skill-row">
                    <div class="skill-name">
                        <img class="img-css" src="images/css3.png" alt="css-png" >
                        <h3>CSS 3</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
        
                <div class="skill-row">
                    <div class="skill-name">
                        <img class="img-js" src="images/javascript.png" alt="js-png" >
                        <h3>JavaScript</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
        
                <div class="skill-row">
                    <div class="skill-name">
                        <img class="img-py" src="images/python.png" alt="python-png" >
                        <h3>Python</h3>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="skill-row">
                    <div class="skill-name">
                        <img class="img-java" src="images/java.png" alt="java-png" >
                        <h3 >Java</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="skill-row">
                    <div class="skill-name">
                        <img class="img-postgresql" src="images/postgresql.png" alt="postgresql-png" >
                        <h3>Postgre SQL</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <hr>
    

    <div id="contact" class="contact-me">
      <h3>Quieres conocer mas sobre mi?</h3>
      <h3>Escribeme o sigueme en mis Redes Sociales.</h3>
      <a class="btn" href="mailto:sebastiansepe@outlook.es">CONTACT ME</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="bottom-container">
    <a class="footer-link" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/sebastian-rodr%C3%ADguez-sepe-424aa814b/">LinkedIn</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="https://github.com/SebastianSepe">Github</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="https://www.instagram.com/sebasepe/?hl=es-la">Instagram</a>
    <p class="copyright">© 2022 Seba Sepe Web.</p>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html
```

> 

```
    html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #40514e;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top right, rgb(245, 228, 228), rgb(245, 230, 201), rgb(243, 243, 206), rgb(216, 248, 216));
}

.hotbar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
  }
  
  li {
    float: left;
  }
  
  li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
  }

.btn-about {
    float:right;
}
  
.top-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.img-profile{
    margin-top: 50px;
}

h1 {
    margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
    font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;
    font-size: 5.625rem;
    color: #2a70cb;
    transition: transform .2s;
}

h1:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}

h2 {
    font-size: 2.0rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #2a70cb ;
    padding-bottom: 10px; 
    margin: 20px 0 10px 0
}

h3 {
    color: #2a70cb;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 5px auto 40px auto;
    line-height: 1;
}

.intro{
    width: 30%;
    margin: 10px auto 10px auto
}

.middle-container {


}


.skills {
    width: 100%;
    display:flex; 
    flex-direction: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    
}
.skill-row {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 40px 20px 40px 20px;

}

.img-html5, .img-py, .img-js, .img-java, .img-css, .img-postgresql {
    width: 20%;
}

.skill-name {
    transition: transform .2s;
}

.skill-name:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}

p {
    line-height: 2;
}

hr {
    border: dotted #d5dada 10px;
    border-bottom: none;
    width: 4%;
    margin: 50px auto 50px auto;
}

.bottom-container {
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 20px 0px 10px;
    margin: 30px auto 0px auto;
}

.contact-me {

    width: 30%;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

.btn {
    background: #83BDF7;
    margin: 100px auto;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #83BDF7, #3E63D4);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #83BDF7, #3E63D4);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #83BDF7, #3E63D4);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #83BDF7, #3E63D4);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #83BDF7, #3E63D4);
    -webkit-border-radius: 8;
    -moz-border-radius: 8;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .btn:hover {
    background: #81B5E6;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #81B5E6, #607DD4);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #81B5E6, #607DD4);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #81B5E6, #607DD4);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #81B5E6, #607DD4);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #81B5E6, #607DD4);
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  a {
      color: #e4f6f6;
      margin: auto 40px auto 40px;
      text-decoration: none;
  }

  a:hover {
      color: #e4f6f6;
  }

.copyright {
    color: #e4f6f6;
    font-size:  0.75rem;
}
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ¿Puedes agregar el código que tienes hasta el momento para poderte ayudar?

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Si claro mira tengo subido a mi repositorio de GitHub https://github.com/SebastianSepe/WebPersonal

Comment: @SebastianSepe los enlaces de código externo no ayudan a realizar una buena pregunta porque pueden expirar por distintos motivos. Las buenas preguntas incluyen todo lo necesario mediante un [example] y no mediante enlaces externos. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta y agregar dicho ejemplo para que la comunidad pueda verlo y ayudarte mejor, gracias.

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias! Ya agregue el codigo html y css a la pregunta!!